# Strange Reactjs setState behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, babeljs, gulp-uglify

I am having a very strange issue with Reactjs's setState function.
It seems to want me to structure pieces of my code in a very specific way or it won't work.
I have no idea why this causes a problem as both structures look the same to me but behave in different ways.

I am using Browserify and Babelify to transpile and gulp-uglify to minify my code. It can be that one or a combination of these building steps causes the issue but I can't tell which (and thus I also don't know if and where to submit an issue)

Here is the relevant section of my code:

```
export default class VideoAppScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.state = { 
            playing: 0,
            playlist: []
        };
    }

    addVideo( video ) {
        this.setState( ( previousState ) => {
            return {playlist: previousState.playlist.push( video )};
        });
    }

    onEnd( event ) {
        console.log( "onEnd", event, this.state );
        this.setState( ( previousState ) => {
            return {playing: previousState.playing + 1};
        });
    }   

    render() {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

As you can see the setState blocks are formatted like this:

```
this.setState( ( previousState ) => {
    return {item: value};
});
```

Like this the addVideo method causes the error: `Uncaught TypeError: t.playlist.push is not a function`.

If I change the blocks to be like this:

```
this.setState( ( previousState ) => {item: value} );
```

The addVideo method works but the onEnd method stops working (without causing an error, it just doesn't update the state)

I can't figure out why these don't work the same way... For formatting purposes I'd like to both have them the same style but it seems that they only work when formatted in either style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns our `Array.prototype.push()` behaves differently than I expected, it returns the length of the array with the new element added onto it [see mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

I was basically resetting my playlist from `[]` to `1` and ofcourse numbers don't have a function push...

I can't tell why the other style of formatting did function as expected... The babelified code seems like it shouldn't work (and didn't work when I changed another function to look the same)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that `previousState` is `undefined`, and that your issue is not cause by spacing.

As specified in the [react's component lifecycle doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods), previous state is ONLY accessible in specific functions:

- `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`,
- `componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` and
- `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`

So if you call your functions at other times, `previousState` will be undefined.

Comment: As you can see in the [setState documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) you can use a function (or an object nextState) as the parameter to setState, this function gets called with the "previousState" (or currentState) and has to return the nextState.

Also when formatted the same only one of the functions experiences a problem the other will work just fine, this tells me that I should be using it correctly (otherwise both wouldn't work) but there is a problem elsewhere.

Comment: You're right. Missed that. Another possible issue: by calling `previousState.playlist.push()` I think you directly also update previousState, which react doesn't like. Could that be the issue here?

Comment: Mhhh it could be... but it **does** work when i structure my code like this `this.setState( ( previousState ) => {playlist: previousState.playlist.push( video )} );` I'm gonna try and remove the uglify step from my build process and debug the bundle file

Comment: Solved it... Array.prototype.push() behaved differently from what i expected.